# 'posts_per_page' in costum page type

Tags: php, posts

i have a problem with the 'posts_per_page'- no matter that i set it to, e.g 10 or 0, it always only show one post!

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'producenter', 'posts_per_page' => 0, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID) ) ); ?>
<p class="loop__title">Andre leverandører:</p>
<ul class="grid__content small">
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
<?php if( get_field( "deloverskrift" ) ): ?>
<p><?php the_field( "deloverskrift" ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</a>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`0` isn't a valid value for `posts_per_page`. WordPress will [see it as empty and default to the `posts_per_page` option](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.3.1/wp-includes/query.php#L2466-L2468). If you want all the posts use [`nopaging` or `posts_per_page => -1`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters).

```
$query = new \WP_Query([
  'post_type' => 'producenter',
  'nopaging' => true,
  'orderby' => 'rand',
  'post__not_in' => [$post->ID],
]);
```

As far as why it's only showing 1 post, is that what you have set in the default posts per page option? Not sure why it would only show one post if you set `posts_per_page` to 10.

Comment: I want to show 5 posts in the side og this homepage, but no matter what i set the post_per_page to, it only show one. http://www.webermarcussen.dk/producenter/qwe/

as far it is just a tes´t site.